# Displaying selected record details in a Pop UP in Spring MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I am implementing a Spring MVC web based application.
I am implementing Audit Log feature. All the operations performed on different tables will be stored in Audit Table. Now Based on some dynamic search criteria I am fetching record from Audit table and displaying the Audit table data in grid in a simple table format, like th & td. Now one of the Column 'X_PK' of this Audit table is the PK for other tables like Table A, B , C etc. on which different activities like Create , Update etc happened. 
I need to implement the feature like if some one click on any of the 'X_PK' record in the Grid, It will display the corresponding table entries (From Table A as example , not from the Audit Log table) where the PK of the record in Table A is the selected value of 'X_PK'. The details needs to be shown in a Pop up.

I was thinking for go ahead with datamodal, but in that case I have to have the data reday with me, in this case based on the selected record, I need to send the parameters in the Controller, fetch corresponding record and then render to UI , in same page but in a Pop Up..

Please suggest.

Comment: Please elaborate what problem you are facing ?

Answer (score 0):

Mwell, You are looking in the good direction with ajax. Basically, you will have something like this. 
Click->
get the cliked element via jQuery->
ajax raquest to an other Spring controller->
ask your app to find this element in the database->
return the object (always with the controller)->
get the response in the ajax call->
do wathever you want with the object in jQuery

I'm not gonna teach you how to make a good Spring MVC controller but I can give you hints on all these steps, also, you can stil dig in Stackoverflow for each step.

Here some reading for you.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-mvc-ajax-jquery/

Comment: Thanks, I will try with this.